# How to display time scale on x axis correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below are my code that read a log file and display the data in a histogram

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


os.chdir('C:/Users/User/anaconda3/envs/yolov7_custom/yolov7-main')

number=[]
times=[]

f=open('log.txt','r')
for row in f:
    row=row.strip().split(' ')
    if row[0] != '' :
    number.append(int(row[0]))
    row5=row[5].split(':')
    times.append(int(row5[0])*100+int(row5[1]))



plt.bar(times,number,color='g',label='File Time')
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Number of people', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

It display the result this attachment
[Histogram of people vs time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fge0.png)

after extracted information from this log file

```
6    03/04/2023 22:13:20
2    03/04/2023 22:14:57
12    03/04/2023 22:18:24
15    03/04/2023 22:20:01
18    03/04/2023 22:21:41
11    03/04/2023 22:23:16
19    03/04/2023 22:24:51
17    03/04/2023 22:26:29
15    03/04/2023 22:28:04
17    03/04/2023 22:29:42
17    03/04/2023 22:31:17
15    03/04/2023 22:32:51
19    03/04/2023 22:34:25
15    03/04/2023 22:36:00
15    03/04/2023 22:37:34
20    03/04/2023 22:39:08
17    03/04/2023 22:40:44


11    03/04/2023 21:47:24
11    03/04/2023 21:48:00
```

Since the x axis refer to 24-hour time format, it does not make sense to display the number like 2180 on x-axis scale. As a result, there a gap in the data(by right after 2140, the next number on x-axis should be 2200). What method can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of integers, `times` can be a list of datetime objects https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this link [Python Mathplotlib: x-axis scale for 24 hours based on 5 minute timestamps for that day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74030974/python-mathplotlib-x-axis-scale-for-24-hours-based-on-5-minute-timestamps-for-t) and copied the code to get what I want. Just create a 24 hrs label that is associate with minutes using np.linspace function. Convert the time into minutes, the bar(time) will scale in proportion to the calculated value in minutes.

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:/Users/User/anaconda3/envs/yolov7_custom/yolov7-main')
x=np.linspace(0,1440,13)
time_labels = ["00:00", "02:00", "04:00", "06:00", "08:00", "10:00", "12:00", 
"14:00", "16:00", "18:00", "20:00", "22:00", "24:00"]
number=[]
times=[]

f=open('log.txt','r')
for row in f:
    row=row.strip().split(' ')
    if row[0] != '' :
    number.append(int(row[0]))
    row5=row[5].split(':')
    times.append(int(row5[0])*60+int(row5[1]))


plt.bar(times,number,color='g',label='File Time')
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Number of people', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(x, labels=time_labels, rotation='vertical') 
plt.show()
```

[Graph showing 24hr time scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDkaV.png)

Comment: manually setting the labels can really bite you down the road when the data changes and the tick locations respond (or don't!) to those changes. Better to use Formatter and Locator objects